# 'private static final' member of Android unit test class changes value to null

Tags: java, android, junit

I have a JUnit test case in an Android project that contains code that looks like this:

```
private static final URI TEST_RESOURCE_URL = TasksService.TASKLIST_RESOURCELIST_URL.resolve("task/test.task");

public void setUp () {
    Log.i("Test", "TEST_RESOURCE_URL=" + TEST_RESOURCE_URL);
}
```

This test class has multiple test methods, some of which refer to (but do not attempt to modify) the value of this constant.  However, when I run these tests (Android 2.2.2), all of these tests but the first one fails, and logcat shows me this:

```
03-03 18:56:41.791: I/Test(12008): TEST_RESOURCE_URL=http://apate.meridiandigital.net/tasks/task/test.task
03-03 18:56:42.101: I/Test(12008): TEST_RESOURCE_URL=null
03-03 18:56:42.131: I/Test(12008): TEST_RESOURCE_URL=null
03-03 18:56:42.151: I/Test(12008): TEST_RESOURCE_URL=null
03-03 18:56:42.281: I/Test(12008): TEST_RESOURCE_URL=null
03-03 18:56:42.311: I/Test(12008): TEST_RESOURCE_URL=null
03-03 18:56:42.341: I/Test(12008): TEST_RESOURCE_URL=null
03-03 18:56:42.361: I/Test(12008): TEST_RESOURCE_URL=null
03-03 18:56:42.391: I/Test(12008): TEST_RESOURCE_URL=null
03-03 18:56:42.391: I/Test(12008): TEST_RESOURCE_URL=null
```

How does a static final field change value like this?  How do I prevent this from happening?  Are there other situations where it might happen?

--- EDIT 1

I have now trimmed the code down to a smaller example that can be included in its entirety.  See below:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}


public class StaticFinalTest extends ServiceTestCase<MyService> {
    public StaticFinalTest() {
        super(MyService.class);
    }

    public static final Object CONST2 = new Object();

    public void testA ()
    {
        assertNotNull (CONST2);
    }

    public void testB ()
    {
        assertNotNull (CONST2);
    }
}
```

When this test runs, testA passes but testB fails.  If testA is commented out, testB passes.

It seems to be important that it is a ServiceTestCase.  A standard JUnit TestCase does not cause the problem.  If 'CONST2' is a String, both tests pass as expected.  Any other reference type seems to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could the test class possibly be being unloaded and reloaded? Can Dalvik even do that? Maybe your constant is being shadowed by something else?

Comment: There's nothing else of the same name anywhere in the project, so I don't suspect it's a shadowing problem.  I think JUnit does attempt to reload classes between test runs, though, by using a different ClassLoader for each invocation.  So the field *may* be a different instance from the second run onwards. In which case the problem is less that it has changed, and more that the initialiser didn't run second time around.

Comment: No, JUnit doesn't reload classes, it just re-instantiates the class before each method.

Comment: Checking with the debugger, the object instance returned by this.getClass() during test execution doesn't change, so it certainly doesn't seem that the class is being reloaded (which should lead to a new Class instance being allocated).

Comment: Maybe it's the toString of the URI instance being wacky?

Comment: Ah, reflection. How do I love thee? See my new answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that [`AndroidTestCase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html) uses reflection to set all non-primitive fields to `null` after each test in [`scrubClass`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/test/AndroidTestCase.java#AndroidTestCase.scrubClass%28java.lang.Class%29). It doesn't check to see if the fields are static or final, so this seems to be the source of the problem.

To solve it, change the field to non-final and set it inside `setUp`. Also, make sure you call `super.setUp()` as the first line of your `setUp` to make sure the test case is properly initialized.

Comment: Dalvik lets this happen? Would other JVMs allow that? This also doesn't jive with 'It seems to be important that it is a ServiceTestCase. A standard JUnit TestCase does not cause the problem. If 'CONST2' is a String, both tests pass as expected. Any other reference type seems to reproduce the problem.'

Comment: I just tried it in a regular JVM, and `setAccessible` has no effect; i.e. I cannot overwrite the final value. Looking over `scrubClass` again I'm not exactly sure what it does. The documentation doesn't seem to match the implementation, but I don't know exactly how it's called. It looks like it only nulls out fields that are themselves test cases which seems rather odd. I would use the workaround and let it go unless you are really curious to dig further. :)

Comment: Turns out this has been a known bug in Android for nearly 3 years.  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4244

Comment: Interestingly, despite the fact that it doesn't work on Sun's JVM, the Java Language Specification seems to suggest that it should be possible to use reflection to modify final fields.  See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.3

Comment: As to why the test passes with the constant being a String, this is because a String is considered a compile-time constant, and the reference to the field is optimized out and replaced with a direct reference to the String itself.  If accessed via reflection, I suspect I would see the field value changing, but as nothing uses it this doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the garbage collector gets rid of it because it cannot know you're still accessing the object using JUnit?

Maybe you should create a method which sets the value initially. Don't forget to annotate it with `@Begin` in order to assure the correct initialization of this variable.

Anyways in a test case, you shouldn't be assuming that previous operations succeeded. The environment you need in a JUnit task should be built up from zero each time.

regards

Comment: If it is, it would appear to be a garbage collector bug.  It shouldn't be possible for the GC to collect an object that can be reached (except via WeakRef<> and the like).  Also, if this were happening, I'd expect the VM to crash, as it wouldn't know that the dangling reference wasn't still valid, and would try to follow it rather than replace it with null.

Comment: @Begin doesn't apply; that appears to be a JUnit 4 addition, and Android uses JUnit 3.  And I'm not assuming previous operations succeeded -- I'm simply using a constant that should be calculated once only at class initialization time.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a scoping issue, is it possible you are nulling  out the referenced value.

```
private static final URI TEST_RESOURCE_URL = TasksService.TASKLIST_RESOURCELIST_URL.resolve("task/test.task");
```

so, if `TasksService` changes, or the call to `resolve()` fails, that would do it.

Comment: TasksService.TASKLIST_RESOURCELIST_URL is itself a constant, so it shouldn't be possible that it's changing.  And resolve() throws IllegalArgumentException if it fails, which should lead to an ExceptionInInitializerError, which isn't happening, so that doesn't sound like the problem, either.